# Tkinter OptionMenu items being read as values for master

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.6

I'm building a temporary interface for my game project so that I can interact with it and test it while waiting on the artwork to come through, which involves drop-down menus to select moves. I just can't seem to get the OptionMenu widget to work.

I've seen plenty of people call it in the style:

```
optionmenu=tkinter.OptionMenu(master, variable, *listitems)
```

And in context, that looks like:

```
UI.window=tkinter.Tk(className='/Temporary Interface')
standard_move=tkinter.StringVar()
standard_move.set('Attack')
standard_moves=tkinter.OptionMenu(master=UI.window,variable=standard_move,*list(UI.party[UI.control.get()].normal_moves))
```

where `UI.party[UI.control.get()]` is an instance of a custom class representing a combatant, and `normal_moves` is a dictionary attribute of the class of the form `{'Move Name':move_function}`, so I'm passing in and unpacking a list of all the names of the moves that the player has on offer as their current character.

Running it yields the error `TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'master'`, and I have no idea why. A bit of help identifying the reason and fixing the bug would be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
OptionMenu(master=UI.window,variable=standard_move,*list(UI.party[UI.control.get()].normal_moves))
```

When you mix keyword arguments and packed positional arguments like this, the `*list` gets bound to the positional parameters first, putting the first element of the list for `master`, the second for `variable`, and the remainder for the option items. Then the keyword arguments try to bind themselves to `master` and `variable`, but a TypeError occurs because those names already have a value.

Consider this simpler example:

```
def f(a,b,c):
    print(a,b,c)

f(a=23, *[42,99])
#TypeError: f() got multiple values for argument 'a'
```

Try passing in the first two arguments without using their names.

```
standard_moves=tkinter.OptionMenu(UI.window,standard_move,*list(UI.party[UI.control.get()].normal_moves))
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't say:

```
OptionMenu(master=UI.window, ...
```

Instead say:

```
OptionMenu(UI.window, ...
```

In other words, don't use the `master` keyword.  The first value is not optional.  Keywords are often used with optional arguments and to make APIs cleaner.

Also, don't use the `variable` keyword either. Just pass in the values.

The system is complaining about "multiple values" for master due to the use of the keyword. I would guess that the system, not seeing a non-keyword argument passed in as master, assumes that master is either None or the first item from *listitems. And then it sees your `master=` and complains about the multiple values.  I just ran this simple test case to prove it.  putting `master=root` and `variable=variable` reproduces your error.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
variable = StringVar()
values = list('abc')
option = OptionMenu(root, variable, *values)
option.pack()
root.mainloop()
```